# Is it valid to define immediately invoked function as normal function and assign it to variable later?

Tags: javascript

If I create an immediately invoked function like this:

```
// assigned to variable and then invoked it
var iife = (foo)();

// defined the function separately
function foo() {
  var bar = 'baz';
  console.log(bar);
}
```

will it be a valid IIFE?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve with this?

Comment: This is a normal function invocation

Comment: Ok, thanks. The answers cleared up the confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The IIFE is like this:

```
(function () {
  // do some here
})();
```

In your example you set foo as regular function and then execute it.

But the foo will be regular variable.
In the real IIFE it doesnt create variable for the function in the current scope, it just executes it.

Comment: You can assign a value to a variable using an IIFE: `var foo = (function() {return 'IIFE'})();`

Answer (score 2):

This code works:

```
function foo (){
    console.log('IIFE');
}

var bar = (foo)(); // IIFE
console.log(bar) // undefined
```

but is no different from:

```
var bar2 = foo(); // IIFE
console.log(bar2) // undefined
```

That is because an IIFE is just a function that invokes itself:

```
(function(){
    // do something and then forget about this function
})();
```

and though your code works I would argue that `var iife = (foo)();` *conceptually* is not an IIFE even though is uses the syntax of one. The use of `foo` inside it means that it executes the function via a reference (the characteristic of normal function invocation). The `()()` is superfluous and you should consequently just use `foo();`

Answer (score 1):

It's **not** an **IIFE**:

```
function foo() {
  var bar = 'baz';
  console.log(bar);
}

var iife = (foo)();
```

It's just the normal function where you're grouping `(foo)` for no reason.
Your normal function should look like this:

```
function foo() {
  var bar = 'baz';
  console.log(bar);
}

foo();
```

**And your IIFE should look like this**:

```
(function () {
  var bar = 'baz';
  console.log(bar);
})();
```